# java.lang.IllegalStateException: No recoveryService set yet! [TOMCAT7 - Spring 3.2 - JPA 2(hibernate impl) - Atomikos 3.9 -

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa-2.0, tomcat7, atomikos

I have developed a webapp with Spring 3.2.2,JPA 2(hibernate implementation) and Atomikos 3.9.0.

So,all seem to work as exepected including local and distribuited transacations.

But if I enable log4j logging for atomikos classes,when I start application I see this exception in console:

WARN 2013-06-23 14:06:20 - ERROR IN RECOVERY
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No recoveryService set yet!
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XATransactionalResource.recover(XATransactionalResource.java:501)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XATransactionalResource.recoverXidsFromResourceIfNecessary(XATransactionalResource.java:614)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XATransactionalResource.endRecovery(XATransactionalResource.java:582)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.TransactionServiceImp.recover(TransactionServiceImp.java:558)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XATransactionalResource.setRecoveryService(XATransactionalResource.java:435)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.system.Configuration.installRecoveryService(Configuration.java:251)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.TransactionServiceImp.prepareConfigurationForPresumedAbortIfNecessary(TransactionServiceImp.java:581)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.TransactionServiceImp.recover(TransactionServiceImp.java:516)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.TransactionServiceImp.init(TransactionServiceImp.java:665)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.BaseTransactionManager.init(BaseTransactionManager.java:181)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.StandAloneTransactionManager.init(StandAloneTransactionManager.java:104)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:257)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:405)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.config.UserTransactionServiceImp.init(UserTransactionServiceImp.java:569)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager.startupTransactionService(UserTransactionManager.java:89)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager.checkSetup(UserTransactionManager.java:77)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager.init(UserTransactionManager.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1614)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1568)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1558)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Why? Application seems to work as expected,but I'n don't know what this exception means?

Someone who can show me the way? :)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
I also met kind of mistake
Use the following method also no problem
...
grant select on sys.dba_pending_transactions to  username;      
grant select on sys.pending_trans$ to username;      
grant select on sys.dba_2pc_pending to username;      
grant execute on sys.dbms_system to username;
```

Answer (score 0):

AtomikosDataSourceBean replace AtomikosNonXADataSourceBean config..

oracle lib up impact

```
<bean id="icDataSource" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.nonxa.AtomikosNonXADataSourceBean">                
    <property name="uniqueResourceName">
        <value>oracle_ic</value>
    </property>     
    <property name="url" value="${ic.jdbc.url}"/>       
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${ic.jdbc.driverClassName}"/>           
    <property name="user" value="${ic.jdbc.username}"/>     
    <property name="password" value="${ic.jdbc.password}"/>     
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5"/>
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="15"/>
    <property name="borrowConnectionTimeout" value="120"/>
```